# Upgrade Magento2.3.5-p1 to Magento 2.3.5-p2

Tags: magento2.3, upgrade, patches, magento2.3.5

How can update Magento2.3.5-p1 with the security patch to Magento2.3.5-p2?

I can not find the p2 patch on the Magento website; https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

Comment: Why done you just use composer? Change the required version for magento in the root composer.json to 2.3.5-p2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how you installed Magento. Also note you should install updates on a development environment and full test your site before replicating on a production environment.

### Composer

```bash
# Run from site root 
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.5-p2 --no-update
composer update
```

### Git (Checkout latest tag)

```bash
# Run from site root
git fetch --tags
git checkout 2.3.5-p2
```

### Archive

- Download & unzip latest archive
- Replace current Magento install files with new Archived versions

**After that run these commands**.
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento --version

Comment: Thanks, saw that I made a small typo on the composer, that's why it did not work in the beginning. Works fine now, thanks

Comment: Magento 2.3.5-p2 supports php 7.2 ?